# PHP mysql turkish character encoding and comparison

Tags: php, mysql, character-encoding

I am trying to filter Turkish names from MySql database through AJAX POST, the English letter words are listing all okay however if I send Ö (which is letter O with dots) the results come for both O and Ö not only Ö

Also what I noticed is the AJAX post is send Ö as %C3%96, anybody can help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please bare my somewhat lengthy response.
Let's start with your second question. `%C3%96` means that the bytes 0xC3 and 0x96 are transmitted. Those two bytes encode [the character `Ö` in utf-8](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/00d6/index.htm).
From this (and that your query yields the described results) I assume that you're using [utf-8 all the way through](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/279170/utf-8-all-the-way-through).

The [lexicographical order](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lexicographical_order) of characters of a [given charset](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html) is determined by the [collation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/charset-literal.html) used.
That's more or less an ordered list of characters. E.g. A,B,C,D,.... meaning `A<B<C`....
But these lists my contain multiple characters in the same "location", e.g.
[A,Ä],B,C,D.... meaning that `A==Ä->true`

___ excursion, not immediately relevant to your question ____
Let's take a look at the "name" of the character `Ö`, it's `LATIN CAPITAL LETTER O WITH DIAERESIS`.
So, the base character is O, it just has some decoration(s).
Some systems/libraries allow you to specify the "granularity"/level/strength of the comparison, see e.g. [Collator::setStrength](http://docs.php.net/manual/en/collator.setstrength.php) of the php-intl extension.

```
<?php
// utf8 characters
define('SMALL_O_WITH_DIAERESIS', chr(0xC3) . chr(0xB6));
define('CAP_O_WITH_DIAERESIS', chr(0xC3) . chr(0x96));

$coll = collator_create( 'utf-8' );
foreach( array('PRIMARY', 'SECONDARY', 'TERTIARY') as $strength) {
    echo $strength, "\r\n";
    $coll->setStrength( constant('Collator::'.$strength) );
    echo '  o ~ ö = ', $coll->compare('o', SMALL_O_WITH_DIAERESIS), "\r\n";
    echo '  Ö ~ ö = ', $coll->compare(CAP_O_WITH_DIAERESIS, SMALL_O_WITH_DIAERESIS), "\r\n";
}
```

prints

```
PRIMARY
  o ~ ö = 0
  Ö ~ ö = 0
SECONDARY
  o ~ ö = -1
  Ö ~ ö = 0
TERTIARY
  o ~ ö = -1
  Ö ~ ö = 1
```

On the primary level all the involved characters (o,O,ö,Ö) are just some irrelevant variations of the character O, so all are regarded as equal.
On the secondary level the additional "feature" `WITH DIAERESIS` is taken into consideration and on the third level also whether it is a small or a capital letter.
But ...MySQL doesn't exactly work that way  ...so, sorry again ;-)
___ end of excursion ____

In MySQL there are collation tables that specify the order. When you select a charset you also implictly select the default collation for that charset, unless you explictly specify one. In your case the implictly selected collation is probably [utf8_general_ci](http://collation-charts.org/mysql60/mysql604.utf8_general_ci.european.html) and it treats ö==o.
This applies to both the table defintion and charset/collation of the connection (the latter being almost irrelevant in your case).
utf8_turkish_ci on the other hand treats ö!=o. That's probably the collation you want.

When you have a table defintion like

```
CREATE TABLE soFoo (
  x varchar(32)
)
CHARACTER SET utf8
```

the default collation for utf8 is chosen -> general_ci -> o=ö
You can specifiy the default collation for the table when defining it

```
CREATE TABLE soFoo (
  x varchar(32)
)
CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_turkish_ci
```

Since you already have a table plus data, you can change the collation of the table   ...but if you do it on the table level you have to use [`ALTER TABLE ... CONVERT`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/alter-table.html) (in case you use MODIFY, the column keeps its "original" collation).

```
ALTER TABLE soFoo CONVERT TO CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_turkish_ci
```

That should pretty much take care of your problem.

---

As a side note there is (as mentioned) a [collation assigned to your connection](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/charset-connection.html) as well. Selecting a charset means selecting a collation. I use mainly [PDO](http://docs.php.net/pdo) when (directly) connecting to MySQL and my default connection code looks like this

```
$pdo = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=test;charset=utf8', 'localonly', 'localonly', array(
    PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES=>false,
    PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_DIRECT_QUERY=>false,
    PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE=>PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION
));
```

note the `charset=utf8`; no collation, so again general_ci is assigned to the connection. And that's why

```
<?php
$pdo = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=test;charset=utf8', 'localonly', 'localonly', array(
    PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES=>false,
    PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_DIRECT_QUERY=>false,
    PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE=>PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION
));

$smallodiaresis_utf8 = chr(0xC3) . chr(0xB6);
foreach( $pdo->query("SELECT 'o'='$smallodiaresis_utf8'") as $row ) {
    echo $row[0];
}
```

prints `1` meaning o==ö.  The string literals used in the statement are treated as utf8/utf8_general_ci.

I could either specify the collation for the string literal explicitly in the statement

```
SELECT 'o' COLLATE utf8_turkish_ci ='ö'
```

(only setting it for one of the two literals/operands; for why and how this works see [Collation of Expressions](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/charset-collation-expressions.html))
or I can set the connection collation via

```
$pdo->exec("SET collation_connection='utf8_turkish_ci'");
```

both result in

```
foreach( $pdo->query("SELECT 'o'[...]='$smallodiaresis_utf8'") as $row ) {
    echo $row[0];
}
```

printing `0`.

edit: and to complicate things even a bit further:
The charset `utf8` can't represent *all* possible characters. There's an even broader character set [`utf8mb4`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/charset-unicode-utf8mb4.html).

Answer (score 0):

The PHP code should be receiving `%C3%96` suitably decoded back to `Ö`.  But if not, then apply the PHP function `urldecode()` to the string.

You will still have the character `Ö`, not `O`; is that OK?

If you get `Ã–`, then there is a mixture of utf8 and latin1.  That is a different problem.